# Java - escape line breaks in CSV for Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv, escaping

I generate csv file in Java code. I use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils to escape values for csv. Some values contain line breaks. When I open the resulted file in Open Office everything is OK. However when I open it in Microsoft Excel 10 the table is garbled - the text on new line is moved to another cell breaking the whole structure. Is there a way to escape line breaks in Java, so that csv will open properly in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSV library to handle this for you. Example with [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)

```
List<Object[]> allRows = getRowsToWriteFromSomewhere();
new CsvWriter(Csv.writeExcel()).writeRowsAndClose(allRows);
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this libary. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)